Why do developers put asymmetric items into a single database table?
A pattern I've seen several times is:

Customer table - CUSTOMER ID, 
Contact table - CUSTOMER_ID, CONTACT_TYPE, CONTACT_NUMBER, OTHER

The use case for the tables is:
SELECT
Home_Num.CONTACT_NUMBER as PHONE_NUMBER,
Mobile.CONTACT_NUMBER as MOBILE_NUMBER,
Email.OTHER as EMAIL,
<other fields>
FROM Customer
LEFT JOIN Contact as Home_Num
    ON Customer.CUSTOMER_ID = Home_Num.CUSTOMER_ID
    and Home_Num.CONTACT_TYPE = 'Home'
LEFT JOIN Contact as Mobile
    ON Customer.CUSTOMER_ID = Mobile.CUSTOMER_ID
    and Mobile.CONTACT_TYPE = 'Mobile'
LEFT JOIN Contact as Email
    ON Customer.CUSTOMER_ID = Email.CUSTOMER_ID
    and Email.CONTACT_TYPE = 'Email'

Usually there is an assumption throughout the rest of the application that "each customer only has one home number" which I assume is made to simplify the UI design. In principle there could be infinitely many contacts attached to each customer but this pattern still turns up in places where that isn't a possibility.
Is there a reason people design things this way? I've seen too many instances like this to assume it is accidental.

People design things like that because (1) 1:1 relationships are much simpler to deal with than 1:n or n:m, and (2) code is written by humans (or LLMs) and thus full of errors and bad assumptions. This is why "falsehoods programmers believe about X" is such a popular blog post genre. (3) The shown design is also weird in other ways, and smells of the EAV (anti-)pattern. Presumably the programmer had hoped to "dynamically" add new contact types as needed, instead of at least representing the contact types as individual nullable columns.

Are you questioning the db schema with two tables, or the query with exactly 3 type if contacts? Please clarify.

Can you clarify your question? Is your concern that the schema supports multiple phone numbers per user, while the UI only supports one? You will have to figure out if it is the schema or the UI which makes the wrong assumption, and this will depend on your business requirement. But neither is inherently wrong. A separate issue with the schema is emails are stored in a column called "Other" which looks like bad design

@JacquesB that's exactly the question. The table design doesn't match the actual use case. I was trying to work out if there is some hidden merit to the design and I think, after posing the question and seeing the responses, that the advantage is that this kind of design is flexible in instances where the business logic hasn't been finalised (i.e. the design doesn't make much sense in the context of the application, but that context isn't necessarily known at the point the table is first designed).

@P.Hopkinson Okay, but I don't think anybody beside the people involved can explain why it was designed by that. It might be due to imprecise specifications or requirements changing over time (e.g perhaps  it was believed the systems had to support multiple phone number, but it ended up that a single number was sufficient). In my experience requirements often start out very general and flexible and then gets more specific over time. Perhaps the schema design have just not been updated correspondingly as the application logic have become more specific.


Is there a reason people design things this way?

Because, "What is your personal UUID?" doesn't produce useful answers as frequently as, "What phone number do we have for you?"
If it did tracking people would be so much easier. But in this world people can't agree on a single system to ID people with and people refuse to memorize an ID for every darn system they interact with.
Which is why you have to bribe people with discounts to get them to carry around loyalty cards with the ID you issued to them.
Without a scheme like that we need something they already have memorized. Most people have and can remember their phone number. But yes, some people have more than one. Some numbers are associated with more than one person.
So no, this is not at all a perfect ID. This is just something to search for in an attempt to pull up their record. Without it you have to hope you're not the first person to bother to ask them how to spell their name. *
 * Transliteration is not perfect either.
 

which I assume is made to simplify the UI design

The UI is just fields that you type in. The UI doesn't care. But this is a User Experience issue. The fewer questions it takes to get to the right record the better.

I typically see this pattern for composite objects for example a customer can have separate billing and shipping addresses (each with multiple fields).
Assuming each customer has exactly one billing and one shipping address this could be represented as a single table with prefixed field names billing_... and shipping_... or it could be represented using two tables.
Generally more tables offer more flexibility for future enhancements/changes and less tables result in simpler queries (I am certain there are exceptions to both of these points).
With a reasonable amount of effort, either option can be refactored to the other one, hence it becomes a matter of opinion about which solution is "better" or "more flexible" and there will be a question about if you are going to need the extra flexibility.
